# Deleting Entity Column from Model - Auto Remove Scaffolding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I need to remove a column from the database in EF 4.3.  The database has updated successfully, but the scaffolding is still there for the CRUD views and errors when trying to access them.  Is there a way to auto remove scaffolding once the model changes, or do I have to manually delete all instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, since I don't know what scaffolding generator you're using. If it's the one that "comes with the box", I'm pretty sure you have to delete the CRUD manually.

The scaffolding generators I'm familiar with are just generators. They don't maintain an awareness of what's been generated, so they don't respond to data model changes. It's a a oneway process.

OTOH, that also means you can probably "eliminate" the scaffolding gunk by rerunning the generator. You'd have to save the customized bits you've added to the scaffolding output, of course, but that may be simpler than deleting what's no longer needed.